# Blender Texturing doesn't show up correctly after repeatedly baked on it even though UV-Mapping fits perfectly

Tags: blender, lighting, 3d-modelling, uv-mapping, texturing

The problem occurs, when I baked lightings & reflections via Principled-BSDF (Cycles) on an "Image Texture"-Node repeatedly. The first times I get excpected solutions and then suddenly the mesh seams to be broken as it keeps showing future bakings incorrectly (image below).

Also when I move an island in the UV-Map nothing seams to changes on the Mesh in the 3D-Viewport. The UV-Texture looks unchanged no matter what I do. Like it has frozen or something.

My Blender Version is: 2.92. Im getting the same problem with 2.83.

I keep getting this problem over and over and I just can't find a solution. Even if I exported the mesh in another project. It just "infects" the other project and I get the same problem there.
I only can repair it if I completely start over.

Please help me. I'm really frustrated with this. This has defeated my blender project now for like the 4th time... :/

[> Screenshot example here <](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9QYNi.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

It appears as if the generated texture coordinates are being used for some reason instead of the UVMap coordinates. If the vector socket of the of the image texture node is unconnected it should use the current selected UVMap.

This may actually be a bug if it's happening after multiple uses of the baking tool.

You should first try connecting the image vector input to the uv output of a texture coordinate node to see if it has any effect. Alternatively try to connect a UVMap node